# Elegant way of getting if element is focused in function QGraphicsItem::shape()

Tags: qt, shapes, qgraphicsitem

In a graphical qt application,
i can learn if my object that inherits from QGraphicsItem is focused in paint method:

Qt Code:

```
void MyQGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *)
{
if (option->state & QStyle::State_HasFocus) {
//if focus some shape

} else {
//if no focus another shape
}
}
```

but i must click it and the shape must change whether it is focused or not.
how can i get if focused information in

Qt Code:

```
QPainterPath QGraphicsItem::shape() const
```

method in an appropriate way?
I think to declare a global variable but i do not like this idea.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QGraphicsItem::hasFocus()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#hasFocus) :

> Returns true if this item is active, and it or its focus proxy has
>   keyboard input focus; otherwise, returns false.

Incidentally, if you want the shape to change when you focus the item, you will need to override focusInEvent() and focusOutEvent() and remember to call prepareGeometryChange() before the shape changes.

Comment: one more question should not i override shape function?

Comment: You don't *have* to override shape() : from the documentation for shape : `The default implementation calls boundingRect() to return a simple rectangular shape`. Depends how far your items are from being rectangular, and how accurate you need collision detection in the scene to be.